# Is it possible to produce a comparison network

Tags: floats, diagrams, rules

Is it possible to produce a comparison network, similar to the one shown in the diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort):

[image]

I've looked at using `\rule`'s, but I can't get them to produce lines in my code. Also how can I add a footnote to the diagram.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In this site we have a policy of one question, one problem and usually post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that sets up the problem you are facing without burdening the users willing to help with that chore. Thar said, have a look at the package `TikZ` to draw the figure and to the command `\footnote`. Happy TeXing! `:)`

Comment: I tried creating the diagram by using simple \draw methods, however it's difficult playing around with the co-ordinates as for some reason the origin for these co-ordinates keeps changing

Comment: @AndrewBrick Time to read the MWE link and think about posting one, then. Impossible to say what might be wrong without seeing some code. (I have no idea what you mean by the origin keep changing.)

Comment: I'm new to Tex, I'm using an online [latex code writer](http://www.sharelatex.com), I'm not really sure how I can show you my error, unless I can upload images into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is use of `matrix of nodes` from `tikz` via a style definiiton called `phase` that drasw a black circle. Then put all the nodes in a matrix form with unique internal labels, connect them with lines via draw command.

```
\tikzset{
phase/.style = {draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

% `phase' is used for controlled phase gates (dots).

\tikzset{
phase/.style = {draw,fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
}
\matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.5cm] (circuit) { % 7 columns
    % First row.
\node [] (start1) {};  
& \node [phase] (c12) {};  
& \node [phase] (c13) {};  
& \node [] (c14) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c15) {}; 
& \node [] (c16) {}; 
& \node [] (c17) {}; 
&\coordinate (end1); \\
    % Second row.
\node [] (start2) {};  
& \node [phase] (c22) {};  
& \node [] (c23) {}; 
\node [right=1pt of c23,phase] (c23b) {};      
& \node [phase] (c24) {};                          
& \node [] (c25) {}; 
\node [right= 1pt of c25,phase] (c25b) {};      
& \node [] (c26) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c27) {}; 
&\coordinate (end2); \\
%    % Third row.
\node [] (start3) {};  
& \node [phase] (c32) {};  
& \node [phase] (c33) {};      
& \node [phase] (c34) {};                        
& \node [] (c35) {}; 
\node [right=7pt of c35, phase] (c35b) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c36) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c37) {}; 
&\coordinate (end3); \\
%     Fourth row.
\node [] (start4) {};  
& \node [phase] (c42) {};  
& \node [] (c43) {}; 
\node [right=1pt of c43, phase] (c43b) {}; 
& \node [] (c44) {};                                     
& \node [] (c45) {}; 
\node [right=13pt of c45, phase] (c45b) {}; 
& \node [] (c46) {}; 
\node [right=1pt of c46, phase] (c46b) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c47) {}; 
&\coordinate (end4); \\
    % 5th row.
\node [] (start5) {};  
& \node [phase] (c52) {};  
& \node [phase] (c53) {};  
& \node [] (c54) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c55) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c56) {};  
& \node [phase] (c57) {}; 
&\coordinate (end5); \\
    % 6th row.
\node [] (start6) {};  
& \node [phase] (c62) {};  
& \node [] (c63) {}; 
\node [right=1pt of c63,phase] (c63b) {};      
& \node [phase] (c64) {};                       
& \node [] (c65) {}; 
\node [right= 1pt of c65,phase] (c65b) {};      
& \node [] (c66) {}; 
\node [right=1pt of c66, phase] (c66b) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c67) {}; 
&\coordinate (end6); \\
%  % 7th row.
\node [] (start7) {};  
& \node [phase] (c72) {};  
& \node [phase] (c73) {};  
& \node [phase] (c74) {};                        
& \node [] (c75) {}; 
\node [right=7pt of c75,phase] (c75b) {};      
& \node [] (c76) {}; 
& \node [phase] (c77) {}; 
&\coordinate (end7); \\
%     8th row.
\node [] (start8) {};  
& \node [phase] (c82) {};  
& \node [] (c83) {}; 
\node [right=1pt of c83, phase] (c83b) {}; 
& \node [] (c84) {};                                     
& \node [] (c85) {}; 
\node [right=13pt of c85, phase] (c85b) {}; 
& \node [] (c86) {}; 
& \node [] (c87) {}; 
&\coordinate (end8); \\
};

% Draw lines.

\draw[thick] (start1) -- (end1)  
(start2) -- (end2) (start3) -- (end3)  (start4) -- (end4) 
(start5) -- (end5)  (start6) -- (end6)  (start7) -- (end7)
(start8) -- (end8) ;
\draw(c12) -- (c22)      (c32) -- (c42)  (c52) -- (c62)  (c72) -- (c82);
\draw(c13)  -- (c33)     (c24) -- (c34);
\draw(c23b)-- (c43b)  (c63b)--(c83b);
\draw(c27) -- (c37)  (c47) -- (c57)  (c53) -- (c73);
\draw(c64) -- (c74)  (c67) -- (c77);
\draw(c15) -- (c55)  (c25b)--(c65b)  (c35b)--(c75b) (c45b)--(c85b);
\draw (c36)-- (c56)  (c46b)--(c66b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following packages/software can do probably more than you require, as it can draw general quantum circuits. Still, it should do as necessary.

[QCircuit](http://physics.unm.edu/CQuIC/Qcircuit/) (I know the page is ugly)

One example would be (this requires downloading [Qcircuit.tex](http://physics.unm.edu/CQuIC/Qcircuit/Qcircuit.tex) from the link and placing it in your folder of the tex-file)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[matrix,frame,arrow]{xypic}
\input{Qcircuit}
\vfuzz2pt

\begin{document}
\[
\Qcircuit @C=1.0em @R=.7em {
& \ctrl{3} & \qw & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{5} & \qw & \qw\\ 
& \qw & \ctrl{2} & \ctrl{3} & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw\\
& \qw & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \ctrl{3} & \qw\\
& \control \qw & \control \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw& \qw& \qw\\
& \qw & \qw & \control \qw & \control \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw \\
& \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \control \qw & \control \qw & \qw
}
\]
\end{document}
```

giving [image].

The extra software I mentioned is this (though probably unnecessary)

[qasm2circ](http://www.media.mit.edu/quanta/qasm2circ/)

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\dx[]` provides a horizontal space of length `\dxO`.  The optional argument specifies a multiple of `\dxO`.  The macro `\link{y1}{y2}` specifies the vertical bars, where `y1` and `y2` are integers that are multiplied by `\dz` which is the grid spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\gline{\rule{2in}{1pt}}
\newlength\dz
\dz=4ex\relax
\newlength\dxO
\dxO=1.33ex\relax
\setstackgap{L}{\dz}
\def\grid{\Longstack{\gline\\\gline\\\gline\\\gline\\\gline\\\gline\\\gline\\\gline}}
\newcommand\link[2]{\makebox[0pt]{\drule[#1\dz]{1pt}{#2\dz}}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\drule[3][0pt]{%
  \setstackgap{S}{0pt}%
  \raisebox{#1}{\Shortstack{\sbullet\\\rule{#2}{\dimexpr#3-#1\relax}\\\sbullet}}}
\def\sbullet{\smash{\raisebox{-2pt}{$\bullet$}}}
\newcommand\dx[1][1]{\hspace{#1\dxO}}
\begin{document}![enter image description here][2]
\noindent\rlap{\grid}
\dx[2]\link{0}{1}\link{2}{3}\link{4}{5}\link{6}{7}
\dx[3]\link{1}{3}\link{5}{7}
\dx\link{0}{2}\link{4}{6}
\dx[3]\link{1}{2}\link{5}{6}
\dx[3]\link{3}{7}
\dx\link{2}{6}
\dx\link{1}{5}
\dx\link{0}{4}
\dx[3]\link{3}{5}
\dx\link{2}{4}
\dx[3]\link{1}{2}\link{3}{4}\link{5}{6}
\end{document}
```

[image]